# running a docker housing a python script, getting error trying to add arguments

Tags: docker

Here's the execution and error:

```
docker run -e AWS_REGION=us-east-1 -e ARCHIVE_BUCKET=foo -e LOG_LEVEL=debug -e S3_OBJECT_SIZE_LIMIT=1200000 test-lfb bucket s3-object s3-object-size
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bucket": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

My Dockerfile is simple:

```
FROM python:3.9
# Or any preferred Python version.
ADD main.py .
RUN pip install boto3 requests beautifulsoup4 python-dotenv
CMD python ./main.py
```

My python script needs environmental variables and runtime arguments.  The docs seem to indicate that you ought to be able to just add the arguments at the end of the docker run command.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

ala: "$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]"  I'm assuming the runtime arguments are ARG here.

Can this not be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that syntax, the first word(s) after the image name are taken as the `[COMMAND]`.  Anything you type as the `docker run` command part *replaces* the Dockerfile `CMD`.

```bash
docker run \
  -e ... \
  test-lfb \
  ./main.py bucket s3-object s3-object-size
# ^^^^^^^^^
#  include the command to run here
```

(You should not normally need to explicitly include the `python` interpreter on the command line.  Make sure the script is executable, `chmod +x main.py`, and that it begins with a "shebang" line `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, and then you can just run `./main.py`.  Check these changes into source control.)

---

If your container setup has both an entrypoint and a command, then the command is passed as arguments to the entrypoint.  There's an alternate pattern of putting the command into the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` and using the "command" field for its arguments.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./main.sh"]
# rather than CMD
```

In this setup your proposed `docker run ... image-name argument list only` syntax will work.

However, this makes a couple of other paths of using the container tricky.  I prefer to use `ENTRYPOINT` for a wrapper script that does first-time setup and then `exec "$@"` runs the actual command, which can conflict with this use.  It can also be convenient to run one-off commands `docker run --rm test-lfb ls /app` for debugging; if you need to override the image's entrypoint then the syntax for this becomes awkward since the alternate command needs to go before the image name, but its arguments after.

---

If it is practical for your application to only consume environment variables and not require command-line arguments, this can wind up being a little bit easier in a container environment.  Especially if your Dockerfile wants to inject a set of always-required arguments or otherwise combine argument lists, this gets tricky quickly.  If you can `docker run -e S3_BUCKET=bucket test-lfb` without overriding the command, then none of the syntactic or ordering considerations matter.

Comment: Thanks so much @David Maze.  This is a terrific response.